# Unity3D Firebase Access Violation

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I use `FirebaseAuth.unitypackage` and `FirebaseDatabase.unitypackage` packages in my project. When I want to test `SignInWithCredentialAsync` and `SetRawJsonValueAsync` operations in the editor, the editor crashes. When I checked the error.log, it says:

```
FirebaseCppApp-5.0.0.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module FirebaseCppApp-5.0.0.dll at 0033:b7cf5c00.
```

Full error.log:

```
Unity Editor [version: Unity 5.6.3f1_d3101c3b8468]

FirebaseCppApp-5.0.0.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module FirebaseCppApp-5.0.0.dll at 0033:b7cf5c00.

Error occurred at 2018-06-22_095612.
C:\Program Files\Unity_5.6.3\Editor\Unity.exe, run by Hammurabi Win01.
74% memory in use.
7923 MB physical memory [1986 MB free].
12608 MB paging file [5375 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134211578 MB free].
Write to location 00000028 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x0dc44170  RSI: 0x00000003  RAX:   0x00000000
RBX:    0x0dc44178  RCX: 0xc19da2b4  RDX:   0x00000000
RIP:    0xb7cf5c00  RBP: 0x4678f409  SegCs: 0x00000033
EFlags: 0x00010206  RSP: 0x4678f270  SegSs: 0x0000002b
R8:    0x4678f208  R9: 0x4678f409  R10:   0x00000000
R11:    0x00000246  R12: 0x00000000  R13:   0x0b2267f8
R14:    0x00000000  R15: 0x00000000

Bytes at CS:EIP:
ff 40 28 48 8b 0b f6 43 08 01 74 08 ff 15 26 a7 

Stack:
0x4678f270: 0dc44178 00000000 0dc44178 00000000 xA......xA......
0x4678f280: 00000000 00000000 000026ec 00000000 .........&......
0x4678f290: fffffffe ffffffff 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f2a0: 4678f378 00000000 b7cb6cd5 00007ff8 x.xF.....l......
0x4678f2b0: 0dc44178 00000000 0dc44218 00000000 xA.......B......
0x4678f2c0: 00000000 00000000 3aad0a60 00000000 ........`..:....
0x4678f2d0: 0dc44170 00000000 00000003 00000000 pA..............
0x4678f2e0: fffffffe ffffffff 4678f378 00000000 ........x.xF....
0x4678f2f0: 2da51300 00000000 2da515a0 00000000 ...-.......-....
0x4678f300: 00000000 00000000 0000000f 00000000 ................
0x4678f310: 5580bf25 0000e36d 2da515a0 00000000 %..Um......-....
0x4678f320: 0dc44218 00000000 4678f4e0 00000000 .B........xF....
0x4678f330: 0dc44218 00000000 b7cbb074 00007ff8 .B......t.......
0x4678f340: 00000000 002bbdb5 00000000 00000000 ......+.........
0x4678f350: 00000000 00000000 82c2bb0a 00007ff8 ................
0x4678f360: 2da51280 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...-............
0x4678f370: 00000000 00000000 0dc44170 00000000 ........pA......
0x4678f380: 00000008 00000000 00000003 00000000 ................
0x4678f390: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f3a0: 2ca25b30 00000000 fffffffe ffffffff 0[.,............
0x4678f3b0: 4678f4e0 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 ..xF....@k......
0x4678f3c0: 00000000 00000000 2ca25b30 00000000 ........0[.,....
0x4678f3d0: 00000000 00000000 82c330c0 00007ff8 .........0......
0x4678f3e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f3f0: 314f5690 00000000 82bb4862 00007ff8 .VO1....bH......
0x4678f400: 00000000 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 ........8.xF....
0x4678f410: 0b2267f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 .g".............
0x4678f420: 2ca25b30 00000000 0b27018f 00000000 0[.,......'.....
0x4678f430: 5580bed5 0000e36d 0aaf6b40 00000000 ...Um...@k......
0x4678f440: 4678ff38 00000000 0dc44218 00000000 8.xF.....B......
0x4678f450: 0aaf6b40 00000000 4678f4e0 00000000 @k........xF....
0x4678f460: 4678f500 00000000 b7cbaf3c 00007ff8 ..xF....<.......
0x4678f470: 82b47e48 00007ff8 82b804d9 00007ff8 H~..............
0x4678f480: 00000000 00000000 82c6aa2c 00007ff8 ........,.......
0x4678f490: 00000000 00000000 82b4749c 00007ff8 .........t......
0x4678f4a0: 4678f548 00000000 b7cae745 00007ff8 H.xF....E.......
0x4678f4b0: 00000000 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 ........8.xF....
0x4678f4c0: 0b2267f8 00000000 82c330c0 00007ff8 .g"......0......
0x4678f4d0: 00000000 00000000 fffffffe ffffffff ................
0x4678f4e0: 4678f5c0 00000000 82b80873 00007ff8 ..xF....s.......
0x4678f4f0: 31e92581 00000000 34beddb0 00000000 .%.1.......4....
0x4678f500: 4678f640 00000000 b7c8ff10 00007ff8 @.xF............
0x4678f510: 2d49a7c0 00000000 4678f548 00000000 ..I-....H.xF....
0x4678f520: 00000000 00000000 82c330c0 00007ff8 .........0......
0x4678f530: fffffffe ffffffff 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f540: 00000000 00000000 2ca25b30 00000000 ........0[.,....
0x4678f550: 0aaf6b40 00000000 00000000 40d24d80 @k...........M.@
0x4678f560: 2ca25b30 00000000 2da51707 00000000 0[.,.......-....
0x4678f570: 2d49a7c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..I-............
0x4678f580: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f590: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f5a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f5b0: 2d49a7c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..I-............
0x4678f5c0: 0dc44218 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 .B......@k......
0x4678f5d0: 034e0000 00000000 31e92580 00000000 ..N......%.1....
0x4678f5e0: 34beddb0 00000000 0000000f 00000000 ...4............
0x4678f5f0: 2da5140b 00000000 2d49a7c0 00000000 ...-......I-....
0x4678f600: 4678f640 00000000 4678f570 00000000 @.xF....p.xF....
0x4678f610: 00000000 00000000 0b2267f8 00000000 .........g".....
0x4678f620: 4678ff38 00000000 00000000 00000000 8.xF............
0x4678f630: 2ca25b30 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 0[.,....@k......
0x4678f640: 4678f6c0 00000000 2da51313 00000000 ..xF.......-....
0x4678f650: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678f660: 00000000 00000000 0000000f 00000000 ................
0x4678f670: 314ea7e0 00000000 0dc44218 00000000 ..N1.....B......
0x4678f680: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678f690: 00000000 00000000 314ea7e0 00000000 ..........N1....
0x4678f6a0: 00000000 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..........N.....
0x4678f6b0: 314ea7e0 00000000 0dc44218 00000000 ..N1.....B......
0x4678f6c0: 4678f740 00000000 2da5057a 00000000 @.xF....z..-....
0x4678f6d0: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678f6e0: 313ccbb8 00000000 348a3678 00000000 ..<1....x6.4....
0x4678f6f0: 034e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..N.............
0x4678f700: 3138dfa8 00000000 3141c420 00000000 ..81.... .A1....
0x4678f710: 313f67e0 00000000 305d2850 00000000 .g?1....P(]0....
0x4678f720: 314ea7e0 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..N1......N.....
0x4678f730: 313f67e0 00000000 313f67e0 00000000 .g?1.....g?1....
0x4678f740: 4678f7c0 00000000 2da4fd50 00000000 ..xF....P..-....
0x4678f750: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678f760: 313ccbb8 00000000 348a3678 00000000 ..<1....x6.4....
0x4678f770: 034e0000 00000000 313ccba0 00000000 ..N.......<1....
0x4678f780: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678f790: 313ccbb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..<1............
0x4678f7a0: 3138dfa8 00000000 3141c420 00000000 ..81.... .A1....
0x4678f7b0: 313ccba0 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..<1......N.....
0x4678f7c0: 4678f820 00000000 2da4fc1c 00000000  .xF.......-....
0x4678f7d0: 2da4fa8f 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...-............
0x4678f7e0: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678f7f0: 00000000 00000000 3141c420 00000000 ........ .A1....
0x4678f800: 313ccbb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..<1............
0x4678f810: 3134ca98 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..41......N.....
0x4678f820: 4678f890 00000000 2da4fa49 00000000 ..xF....I..-....
0x4678f830: 00000000 00000000 2a88e5d8 00000000 ...........*....
0x4678f840: 034e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..N.............
0x4678f850: 3144b3e0 00000000 313ccbb8 00000000 ..D1......<1....
0x4678f860: 00000000 00000000 3134ca98 00000000 ..........41....
0x4678f870: 3144b3e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..D1............
0x4678f880: 3134c7c8 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..41......N.....
0x4678f890: 4678f950 00000000 2da4f590 00000000 P.xF.......-....
0x4678f8a0: 00000000 00000000 347cf760 00000000 ........`.|4....
0x4678f8b0: 314442a0 00000000 00000001 00000000 .BD1............
0x4678f8c0: 311153c0 00000000 31423230 00000000 .S.1....02B1....
0x4678f8d0: 00000000 00000000 314f56f0 00000000 .........VO1....
0x4678f8e0: 00000000 00000000 314f56f0 00000000 .........VO1....
0x4678f8f0: 310c3060 00000000 00000001 00000000 `0.1............
0x4678f900: 00000001 00000000 314442a0 00000000 .........BD1....
0x4678f910: 3144b3e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..D1............
0x4678f920: 3134c7c8 00000000 314442a0 00000000 ..41.....BD1....
0x4678f930: 00000001 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..........N.....
0x4678f940: 314f56f0 00000000 303e8620 00000000 .VO1.... .>0....
0x4678f950: 4678f990 00000000 2da4f299 00000000 ..xF.......-....
0x4678f960: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678f970: 2da4f220 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff  ..-............
0x4678f980: 31444280 00000000 034e0000 00000000 .BD1......N.....
0x4678f990: 4678fa20 00000000 2da4ed7f 00000000  .xF.......-....
0x4678f9a0: 4678fad0 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 ..xF....@k......
0x4678f9b0: 2da4ecd6 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...-............
0x4678f9c0: 305d4500 00000000 305d4500 00000000 .E]0.....E]0....
0x4678f9d0: 305d4500 00000000 00000000 00000000 .E]0............
0x4678f9e0: 034e0000 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 ..N.....8.xF....
0x4678f9f0: 00000000 00000000 4678f9b0 00000000 ..........xF....
0x4678fa00: 2da4ebf0 00000000 fffffffe ffffffff ...-............
0x4678fa10: 0b950000 00000000 2da4ebf0 00000000 ...........-....
0x4678fa20: 4678fad0 00000000 2da341ad 00000000 ..xF.....A.-....
0x4678fa30: 30cbca10 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...0............
0x4678fa40: 2da3410b 00000000 4678f840 00000000 .A.-....@.xF....
0x4678fa50: 4678fb10 00000000 305d4820 00000000 ..xF.... H]0....
0x4678fa60: 305d4500 00000000 31444940 00000000 .E]0....@ID1....
0x4678fa70: 034e0000 00000000 2a88e5d8 00000000 ..N........*....
0x4678fa80: 034e0000 00000000 305d4820 00000000 ..N..... H]0....
0x4678fa90: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678faa0: 00000000 00000000 4678fa40 00000000 ........@.xF....
0x4678fab0: 0b271d10 00000000 349f4be8 00000000 ..'......K.4....
0x4678fac0: 0ab490e6 00000000 0b271d10 00000000 ..........'.....
0x4678fad0: 4678fb10 00000000 2da33afd 00000000 ..xF.....:.-....
0x4678fae0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678faf0: 2da33ab0 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff .:.-............
0x4678fb00: 3138dc30 00000000 034e0000 00000000 0.81......N.....
0x4678fb10: 4678fba0 00000000 2da33796 00000000 ..xF.....7.-....
0x4678fb20: 4678fc30 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 0.xF....@k......
0x4678fb30: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678fb40: 31444500 00000000 00000000 00000000 .ED1............
0x4678fb50: 00000000 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..........N.....
0x4678fb60: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678fb70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fb80: 2da33730 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 07.-............
0x4678fb90: 0b95000e 00000000 2da33730 00000000 ........07.-....
0x4678fba0: 4678fc30 00000000 2da3337c 00000000 0.xF....|3.-....
0x4678fbb0: 4678fcc0 00000000 0aaf6b40 00000000 ..xF....@k......
0x4678fbc0: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678fbd0: 314f3b10 00000000 314f3b10 00000000 .;O1.....;O1....
0x4678fbe0: 00000000 00000000 034e0000 00000000 ..........N.....
0x4678fbf0: 0b2267f8 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .g".....8.xF....
0x4678fc00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fc10: 0b271d10 00000000 2b1e0058 00000000 ..'.....X..+....
0x4678fc20: 2baf59fd 00000000 0b271d10 00000000 .Y.+......'.....
0x4678fc30: 4678fcc0 00000000 0aaf6c42 00000000 ..xF....Bl......
0x4678fc40: 00000020 00000000 00000000 00007ff8  ...............
0x4678fc50: 00000000 00000000 82b1232d 00007ff8 ........-#......
0x4678fc60: 2baf59fd 00000000 00000000 00000000 .Y.+............
0x4678fc70: 4678ff38 00000000 30cbc850 00000000 8.xF....P..0....
0x4678fc80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fc90: 034e0000 00000000 82b1228b 00007ff8 ..N......"......
0x4678fca0: 2ca25b30 00000000 2ca25b30 00000000 0[.,....0[.,....
0x4678fcb0: 0aaf6b40 00000000 4678fd00 00000000 @k........xF....
0x4678fcc0: 4678fd00 00000000 82c35827 00007ff8 ..xF....'X......
0x4678fcd0: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000001 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678fce0: 2d49a7c0 00000000 2ca25b30 00000000 ..I-....0[.,....
0x4678fcf0: 00000000 00000000 c195265b 00007ff8 ........[&......
0x4678fd00: 0b2267f8 00000000 00000001 00000000 .g".............
0x4678fd10: 00000018 00000000 2d49a7c0 00000000 ..........I-....
0x4678fd20: 299d4600 00000000 30cbc850 00000000 .F.)....P..0....
0x4678fd30: 00000000 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 ........8.xF....
0x4678fd40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fd50: 00000001 00000000 2a362d00 00000000 .........-6*....
0x4678fd60: 00000018 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fd70: 30cbc850 00000000 82c8a045 00007ff8 P..0....E.......
0x4678fd80: 4678fdf0 00000000 4678fdf0 00000000 ..xF......xF....
0x4678fd90: 00000000 00000000 001f0000 00000000 ................
0x4678fda0: 00000000 00000000 82c7787d 00007ff8 ........}x......
0x4678fdb0: 00000000 00000000 2a362d00 00000000 .........-6*....
0x4678fdc0: 00000018 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 ........8.xF....
0x4678fdd0: 00000000 00000000 82b1759c 00007ff8 .........u......
0x4678fde0: 4678fe50 00000000 4678fe50 00000000 P.xF....P.xF....
0x4678fdf0: 00000000 00000000 82b30000 00007ff8 ................
0x4678fe00: 4678fe60 00000000 82b14c69 00007ff8 `.xF....iL......
0x4678fe10: 2af644b0 00000000 4678ff38 00000000 .D.*....8.xF....
0x4678fe20: 4678ff38 00000000 4678fe60 00000000 8.xF....`.xF....
0x4678fe30: 2ca25b30 00000000 82b58059 00007ff8 0[.,....Y.......
0x4678fe40: 1656f65c 00000911 4678ff38 00000000 \.V.....8.xF....
0x4678fe50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fe60: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x4678fe70: 2a362d00 00000000 00000000 00000000 .-6*............
0x4678fe80: 4678ff38 00000000 2ca25b30 00000000 8.xF....0[.,....
0x4678fe90: 30cbc850 00000000 82b88439 00007ff8 P..0....9.......
0x4678fea0: 2ca25b30 00000000 00000000 00000000 0[.,............
0x4678feb0: 30cbc850 00000000 2a362d00 00000000 P..0.....-6*....
0x4678fec0: 00000000 00000000 82bb37cb 00007ff8 .........7......
0x4678fed0: 303fde60 00000000 00000000 00000000 `.?0............
0x4678fee0: 30cbc850 00000000 00000000 00000000 P..0............
0x4678fef0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ff00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ff10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ff20: 00000000 00000000 82c6841d 00007ff8 ................
0x4678ff30: 0000640c 00000000 00000000 00000000 .d..............
0x4678ff40: 0b23bed0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..#.............
0x4678ff50: 00000000 00000000 bf503034 00007ff8 ........40P.....
0x4678ff60: 0b23bed0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..#.............
0x4678ff70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ff80: 00000000 00000000 c19b1431 00007ff8 ........1.......
0x4678ff90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ffa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ffb0: 00000000 00000000 bea9bf10 00007ff8 ................
0x4678ffc0: 4678e350 00000000 4678e350 00000000 P.xF....P.xF....
0x4678ffd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678ffe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x4678fff0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................

Module 1
C:\Program Files\Unity_5.6.3\Editor\OpenRL_pthread.dll
Image Base: 0x80000000  Image Size: 0x0000f000
File Size:  42496       File Time:  2017-07-23_105438
Version:
   Company:    Open Source Software community LGPL
   Product:    POSIX Threads for Windows LPGL
   FileDesc:   MS C 32 bit
   FileVer:    2.9.0.0
   ProdVer:    2.9.0.0

Module 2
C:\Program Files\Unity_5.6.3\Editor\OpenRL.dll
Image Base: 0x80000000  Image Size: 0x00c30000
File Size:  12654592    File Time:  2017-07-23_105438
Version:
   Company:    Imagination Technologies, Inc.
   Product:    OpenRL™
   FileDesc:   OpenRL™ Library
   FileVer:    1.5.100.0
   ProdVer:    1.5.100.0

Module 3
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP100.dll
Image Base: 0x53ec0000  Image Size: 0x00098000
File Size:  608080      File Time:  2011-06-11_011538
Version:
   Company:    Microsoft Corporation
   Product:    Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010
   FileDesc:   Microsoft® C Runtime Library
   FileVer:    10.0.40219.325
   ProdVer:    10.0.40219.325

Module 4
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
Image Base: 0x53f60000  Image Size: 0x000d2000
File Size:  829264      File Time:  2011-06-11_011538
Version:
   Company:    Microsoft Corporation
   Product:    Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010
   FileDesc:   Microsoft® C Runtime Library
   FileVer:    10.0.40219.325
   ProdVer:    10.0.40219.325


== [end of error.log] ==
```

It does not happen all the time but frequently. Let say, 1/2 of my tests.

```
public void SendData() {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    Credential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(accessToken);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCompleted) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                firebaseUser.DisplayName, firebaseUser.UserId);

            // FIREBASE DATABASE INIT
            // THIS IS EDITOR ONLY CODE. Firebase handles differently in the client.
            FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://<<hidden>>.firebaseio.com/");

            // FIREBASE DATABASE SAVE (Root Reference)
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
            User user = new User(firebaseUser.UserId, "Eray", "test@testing.me");
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
            reference.Child("users").Child("Eray").SetRawJsonValueAsync(json).ContinueWith(setValueTask => {
                Debug.Log("Set Completed: " + setValueTask.IsCompleted);
                Debug.Log("Successful: " + (setValueTask.Exception != null));
            });

        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Firebase SignIn is NOT completed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are using different firebase versions? firebase database and firebase auth are from the same release version?

Comment: They all are the same version. I am just not sure about the version. It looks like at least 5.0.0 (Release Notes include that version).

Comment: Okay, I'm just saying because I had the exact same error, and it was because I imported Firebase-Database from SDK v5.0.0, and a month later, I imported Firebase-Messages from SDK v5.1.1 which caused the same error you mentioned here. 
After removing v5.1.1 and replacing with v5.0.0, it was solved.  
Just mentioning in-case other people would face the same issue.

Comment: I too have this problem. At first it was intermittent crashes but lately it's every time I compile. Has made Unity unusable. My error log: https://pastebin.com/vjC9cSXh

Answer (score 0):

Adding a folder with your package name (i.e. `com.companyName.appName`) into AppData/Local worked for me. Found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/j6u307/unity_crashing_on_getreference_call/)